# conditional probability, independent events

Tags: probability, independence

I am facing several dificulties to prove the following result : Being $B_1,B_2$ independent events ,and $C$ a possible event , prove that:

$$P(B_1,B_2|C)=P(B_1|C)\times P(B_2|C)$$

and I am not sure if the following result is true: (assuming the other one accurate it was the result I came with)

$$P(C|B_1,B_2)=\frac{P(C|B_1)\times P(C|B_2)}{P(C)}$$

$B_1,B_2$ represents the intersection of $B_1$ and $B_2$

If someone could show me a prove of the first one and seing if the second equality is true or untrue it would be aprecciate.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true in general that $P(B_1\cap B_2\mid C)=P(B_1\mid C)P(B_2\mid C)$.

The condition of independence of $B_1,B_2$ makes no difference.

For a counterexample, let $C:=B_1\Delta B_2=(B_1\setminus B_2)\cup(B_2\setminus B_1)$ and assume that both sets $B_1\setminus B_2$ and $B_2\setminus B_1$ have positive probability.

Then $P(B_1\cap B_2\mid C)=0$ but $P(B_1\mid C)P(B_2\mid C)>0$.

Also it is not true in general that $P(C\mid B_1\cap B_2)P(C)=P(C\mid B_1)P(C\mid B_2)$.

Same counterexample.

Comment: thanks , do you think that first equation olds if c is a conjunt in wich  P(B1∩B2∣C)>0 ,and P(B1∣C)P(B2∣C)>0

Comment: `\Delta` gives symmetric difference symbols that are more in line than `\triangle`.

Comment: No. In the counterexample we can slightly change $C$ in such a way that $P(B_1\cap B_2\mid C)>0$ and still no equality.

Comment: @Did Thanks, I will try to remember.